# iOS 7 Text to speech API not working

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, text-to-speech

I recently implemented the iOS 7 TTS API and it's not working.

In the .h:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate>
```

In the .m:

```
@interface MainViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVSpeechSynthesizer* talker;
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    AVSpeechUtterance *utter = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:@"Hello World"];
    utter.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-US"];
    [utter setRate:0.2f];
    if (!self.talker) {
        self.talker = [AVSpeechSynthesizer new];
    }
    self.talker.delegate = self;
    [self.talker speakUtterance:utter];
 }
```

I have also added `AVFoundation.framework`. I don't know what the problem is but nothing is being spoken. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it speaking anything? Have to ask, but is the sound turned on so that you can hear it? Property or not, that should work fine so long as it all occurs in the same method.

Comment: Also, set the delegate. The delegate methods will fire if things are working, even if you can't hear anything. Your code neglects to set any delegate.

Comment: @matt I updated my question... and I looked at the working code from github and did the same in my code... I also set the delegate... But for some reason, it still doesn't work

Comment: @remus Yes the volume is on full, and it's located in one method... but it's not speaking anything.

Comment: Any reason you're using both @import and #import? Can't see that causing a conflict, but maybe worth a shot. To Matt's point, your updated code looks more in line with that example, which makes me think it's an audio conflict or mute.

Comment: Ok I restarted xcode, and cleaned, and now it works!

Comment: What was the solution then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating your synthesizer and then your method ends and the synthesizer vanishes in a puff of smoke before it can do anything. If you want it to speak, retain it (e.g. in a property) so that it lives song enough to do so.

Comment: Working code here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch14p656textToSpeech/ch27p924textToSpeech/ViewController.m Go thou and do likewise.

Comment: "I did that" But not in the code you originally gave. You asked what was wrong with that code, I told you something that was seriously wrong with it. If you've changed it, show your new code.

Answer (score 1):

import below statement

```
#import<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

and write this code in to your button press

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:_txtText.text];
//utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceMaximumSpeechRate;
utterance.rate = 0.30;
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-US"];
[synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
synthesizer = nil;
NSArray* speechVoices = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice speechVoices];
NSLog(@"Voices: (%lu) %@", (unsigned long)speechVoices.count, speechVoices);
```

working 100% for me